# Asymptotic expansion of the Schrödinger kernel?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation, schrodinger-operators, integral-kernel

[My stackexchange post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275830/schrodinger-kernels-on-manifolds) was somewhat unsatisfactory (also because I may not have stated clear enough what my interest was).  So here it goes!

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold and $\Delta$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator. It is well-known that the solution operator to the heat equation $e^{t \Delta}$ is smoothing for $t>0$ and has a smooth integral kernel $k_t(x, y) \in C^\infty(M \times M)$. Furthermore, $k_t$ has an asymptotic expansion
$$ k_t(x, y) \sim \underbrace{(4 \pi t)^{-n/2} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{4t} \mathrm{dist}(x, y)^2 \right)}_{:= e_t(x, y)} \sum_{j=0}^\infty t^j \Phi_j(x, y) $$
meaning that
$$ \left| k_t(x, y) - e_t(x, y) \sum_{j=0}^N t^j \Phi_j(x, y) \right| \leq C t^{N+1}$$
uniformly in $x$ and $y$ in a neighborhood of the diagonal.

Now by by formally substituting $t \rightarrow it$, one gets the formal asymptotic series
$$ e_{it}(x, y) \sum_{j=0}^\infty (it)^j \Phi_j(x, y),$$
which has the property that it formally (i.e. termwise, as asymptotic series in $t$) solves the Schrödinger equation $ \left(i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \Delta\right)k_t = 0.$

**Now my question is the following: Does this asymptotic series have any relation to the solution operator $e^{it\Delta}$ of the Schrödinger equation, or to its distribution kernel?**

Answer (score 4):

In this 2006 [paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_2006__56_6/AIF_2006__56_6_1903_0/AIF_2006__56_6_1903_0.pdf) you can find the long-time asymptotics of the Schrödinger kernel on Riemannian manifolds. My understanding is that the analytic continuation to imaginary time gives the correct answer provided there are no zero-energy resonant states.

Answer (score 4):

No, in general, the expansion in small times of the heat kernel $k_t(x,y)$ does not tell much about the Schrodinger semigroup. 
You may think about the circle case for which the kernel of $e^{t \Delta}$ has an expansion at any order

$
k_t(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}} e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{4t}} (1 +O(t^m))$

but the Schrodinger semigroup $e^{it \Delta}$ has [a rather complicated behavior](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/gausum.pdf). The Schrodinger kernel in that case is actually a distribution. If $t$ is a rational multiple of $2\pi$, it is a finite linear combination of delta functions  which is interestingly connected to Gauss sums.